# How get Expression tree of regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working in the conversion algorithm obtains a DFA from a regular expression. This algorithm is limited to only **operators (*, |, . )**.

For those who do not know the meaning of each operator can check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

The algorithm analyzes the nodes of a tree that is created from a regex

**Here** I attached an image showing a table with the functions voidable first position and last position which is applied to each node of the tree created.

[image]

**For example**: If apply for this regex  `(a│b)*a(a│b)` analysis with the table.

The **first step** of the algorithm is to add the symbol `#` at the end  `(a│b)*a(a│b)#` and `enumerate` each symbol:

[image: regex]

Later the tree  is constructed (**my problem**) and each node is discussed in the above table, remaining so. To the right of the node in `{}` PmraPos(first position) and left at `{}` UtmaPos (end position).

[image]

**Problem:** In java I was trying to build the tree we spoke with `Stack` but got good results, because, as you can see in the picture, not all nodes have two children. I want **help** for building the tree.

**Note:** What I did to try to build the tree, it was to pass the regular expression to its `postfix` form.

Comment: Have you used some automatic translation for the post? The image is not in English, and "I was trying to build the tree we spoke with batteries but got good results" sounds really strange to me.

Comment: have you checked `ANTLR` parser/lexer for this.

Comment: I do not speak English very well, I was referring to the `Stack` in Java

Comment: @aioobe Image are in english  now

Comment: @L.Flor, I see "Utmapos (c)" in the lower right corner. That doesn't look like English to me.

Comment: @aioobe Take it as the name of any attribute that each node will have. The help I ask is just to get the tree of expression. The table and all it explain is the procedure of the algorithm. The algorithm does not end here, it is a longer procedure. As I say, this is just an explanation of why I want to I need help build the tree of the regular expression, because each node is analyzed.